# How do I change the background colour in the Play class?

Tags: java, swing

I want to change the color of the background and a clear window without creating a new `JFrame`. Any suggestions?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Dodge EM");
        frame.setSize(1000, 700);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        placeComponents(frame);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);

    }

    private static void placeComponents(JFrame frame) {
        frame.setLayout(null);

        JLabel dodgeEM = new JLabel("Dodge EM");
        dodgeEM.setForeground (Color.RED);
        dodgeEM.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 30));
        dodgeEM.setBounds(440,10,300,150);
        frame.add(dodgeEM);


        JButton playButton = new JButton("Play");
        playButton.setBounds(460,150,95,30);
        frame.add(playButton);

        ActionListener play = new Play();
        playButton.addActionListener(play);

        JButton scoresButton = new JButton("Scores");
        scoresButton.setBounds(460,250,95,30);
        frame.add(scoresButton);

        JButton helpButton = new JButton("Help");
        helpButton.setBounds(460,350,95,30);
        frame.add(helpButton);

        JButton quitButton = new JButton("Quit");
        quitButton.setBounds(460,450,95,30);
        frame.add(quitButton);

    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Play extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Play button has been pressed");
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: 1) `frame.setLayout(null);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) `new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 30)` better to use the defined constants, thus `new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD, 30)`

Answer (score 1):

Rather then creating a new class, you can add the action listener to your button like shown below

```
      playButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            //do stuff onclick
            frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.yellow);
        }
    });
```